# The little loop runs too often

Tags: linux-mint, autokey

i have wrote a simple Phyton in AutoKey script.
I expected the cursor **runs one line down**. But the cursor **runs many 1000 lines down**. That takes some minutes.

```
for i in range(0, 1): 
    keyboard.press_key('<down>')
```

i tried to uninstall other software that could maybe influence the keyboard negative. i uninstalled espanso ( https://espanso.org/install/ ) but it changes nothing.

The result is also visible in this live stream (german voice): https://youtu.be/r9QYQv5h2HU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Down Key hangs permanently. The Loop was running correct.
Its needet to release it manually by using `keyboard.release key('<down>')`

```
for i in range(0, 1): 
    keyboard.press_key('<down>')
    keyboard.release_key('<down>')
```